# Failed to install log4net from NuGet in a .NET Standard library project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, log4net

I just started on this project and it is basically empty. When I try to install log4net in nuget package manager, the following error is shown in the output.

> A PackageReference for 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' was included in your
>   project. This package is implicitly referenced by the .NET SDK and you
>   do not typically need to reference it from your project. For more
>   information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs

I simply do not understand this message, why it tells me there's a .net core thing in my project?

When it says this package is implicitly referenced, does it mean that I have loaded this package? However, I don't quite believe that since I could not use anything from log4net.

BTW, the same error happens when I try to install an old version of netsoft json.

I created the project as a .NET Standard 1.1 project.

Am I misconfiguring something or I have a totally wrong idea about the whole thing?

Comment: are you using .net core or .net framework?

Comment: @sLowDowN I created the project as a .net standard 1.1 project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I created the project as a .net standard 1.1 project

According to the [Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html), log4net only supports **.NET Standard 1.3 or higher**. You will either have to target .NET Standard 1.3+ or find a logging library that has support for .NET Standard 1.1.

The lower the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) version that you target, the fewer APIs are available, and the less likely it will be that 3rd party libraries can target it.

Comment: Shame on me... but the error message from nuget should absolutely be clearer... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@NightOwl888, I have looked into the issue tracker of log4net and found log4net is  not available for .net standard 2.0. Please refer : 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-572

Comment: [.NET Standard 1.3 will work on all platforms that .NET Standard 2.0 supports.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support)